# failing to connect to iTunes connect for auto-renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I do not usually ask question here. This is not a programmatic question. I have coded my App perfectly. I have used other peoples code, and it displays products from their iTunes connect. How ever when I link it to my account it has proven unsuccessful.

I only get this message above my auto-renewable subscription:

Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below.

How ever that being said, it just seems inconvenient I need to submit a new App version and website link to a privacy URL when it is destined to be declined. I do intend to publish this App. Support is welcome!

Comment: In app purchase items are available to test before you submit them for review. Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! Yes I am testing on a real device.

Comment: I've logged out of my account on my phone.